# no wireless on Kubuntu 14.04/ Dell Vostro 1540

Tags: 14.04, wireless, kubuntu

I recently installed Kubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Vostro 1540. It recognizes wireless during the installation, but after restart, I can't connect via wireless- it doesn't keep the connection I created for the installation, and after I recreate, it doesn't connect. I found nothing about it in askubuntu and Google.
I went to the driver manager, and it says it is using:
"Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller".

Now, it's the same proprietary driver it's been using during installation. What's wrong? Why doesn't it work after restart? And most important of all, how can I make it work? It worked perfectly with Kubuntu 13.10. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

The output of `lsmod | grep -e brcm -e wl -e b43` is:

```
brcmsmac   563041  0
cordic      12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil    15618  1 brcmsmac
b43        387371  0
mac80211   630653  2 b43, brcmsmac
cfg80211   484040  3 b43, brcmsmac, mac80211
ssb         62379  1 b43
bcma        52096  3 b43, brcmsmac
```

Thank you

Comment: Please try the native driver. From a terminal: sudo modprobe -r wl; sudo modprobe -r lib80211; sudo modprobe -r cfg80211. If the latter two are no longer present and thus not removed, that's fine, just continue: sudo modprobe brcmsmac. Any improvement?

Comment: No it says:modprobe FATAL: Module WL not found. modprobe FATAL: Module cfg80211 is in use. What should I do now? Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: lsmod | grep -e brcm -e wl -e b43 Thanks.

Comment: Dear Chili555, I did as you wrote, and added the results to the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Now the correct modules are loaded. Is there any improvement?

Comment: Yes, thank you so, so much. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver that seems to work best for your BCM4313 is brcmsmac and not wl. Let's remove wl and let brcmsmac take over. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After it finishes, reboot. Your wireless should be working well.